# NSwag - using date format for string property in auto-generated DTOs

Tags: c#, swagger, nswag

I am using NSwag to generate DTOs. In the yaml I specify a property with a date format as follows:

```
 User:
    type: object
    additionalProperties: false
    properties:
    createdAt:
        type: string
        format: date
```

This generates the C#:

```
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("createdAt")]
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(DateFormatConverter))]
    public System.DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; } = default!;
```

Which uses the newly generated class of `DateFormatConverter`:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "13.15.10.0 (NJsonSchema v10.6.10.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
internal class DateFormatConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<System.DateTime>
{
    public override System.DateTime Read(ref System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader reader, System.Type typeToConvert, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dateTime = reader.GetString();
        if (dateTime == null)
        {
            throw new JsonException("Unexpected JsonTokenType.Null");
        }

        return System.DateTime.Parse(dateTime);
    }

    public override void Write(System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter writer, System.DateTime value, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    }
}
```

However, the `JsonException` throws a `not found` error, which is solved by adding `using System.Text.Json` statement. This gets deleted at build though, as the file is regenerated.

Is there a better way to implement the `date` format? Could I add the `using` statement in config somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. I am facing the exact same problem.

Comment: yes! It was quite a small thing, i'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I used `date`, but should've been using `date-time`.

```
createdAt:
    type: string
    format: date-time
```

This should create:

```
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("createdAt")]
public System.DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; } = default!;
```

No converter needed!